# Once I've returned a reply the function doesn't continue. Is there a way I can return a value and then carry on?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a bot that you can talk to. I am using if functions to check if certain words are used and therefore have a reply. I do this inside of a function and use return to print the reply. If two things are said I want it to be able to say both of them, the problem is once I've returned a reply the function doesn't continue. Is there a way I can return a value and then carry on? Here is the main focus and after the entirety of my code.

```
    # Reply
    if thank == True:
        return "It's my pleasure\n"
    if greet == True:
        return "How are you?\n"
```

And the main code:

```
# Chat Bot
import random

print("Hi!\n")
greetings = ["hi","hey","hello","yo","wassup"]
thanks = ["cheers","thanks","thx"]

def reply(x):
    greet = False
    # Greetings
    for item in greetings:
        if item in x:
            greet = True

    # Thanks
    thank = False
    for item in thanks:
        if item in x:
            thank = True


    # Reply
    if thank == True:
        return "It's my pleasure\n"
    if greet == True:
        return "How are you?\n"

    else:
        randomAnswers = ["I like cheese.", "That's Cool.", "You are a robot.", "I am not a robot.", "I like music.", "I want to visit australia.","Do you like me?","You're cool."]
        num = random.randint(0, len(randomAnswers) - 1)

        return randomAnswers[num]



while 1:

    userMessage = input("Message: ").lower()
    print()
    print(reply(userMessage))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning immediately, collect your responses in a list, then return that list at the end:

```
def reply(x):
    responses = []

    if any(item in x for item in thanks):
        responses.append("It's my pleasure\n")
    if any(item in x for item in greetings):
        responses.append("How are you?\n")

    if not responses:
        randomAnswers = ["I like cheese.", "That's Cool.", "You are a robot.", "I am not a robot.", "I like music.", "I want to visit australia.","Do you like me?","You're cool."]
        responses.append(random.choice(randomAnswers))

    return responses
```

Comment: You should also consider wrapping up the repetitive logic to enable testing along the way. All of those 'for x in list: if x in input' lines could be moved to a function such as `is_input_in`.

Comment: I shall also do this Sean thanks. Also Martjin thanks for the correction to random.choice surprised I have never come across that before.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way I can return a value and then carry on?

Yes! Most languages can't do this, but Python can. Just `yield` instead of `return`ing. That gives up a value, but lets your function keep running. Here's an example:

```
def return_some_values(zero, one, two):
    if zero:
        yield 0
    if one:
        yield 1
    if two:
        yield 2
```

So, this function can return anywhere from 0 to 3 values before it finishes.

But how do you use it?

When you call a function that `yield`s (a "generator function"), what you get back is a generator. A generator, like a list, is iterable—that is, you can loop over it, or copy it into a list or a set, etc. (Unlike a list, it's not a sequence—you can't index it, you can only loop over it once and then it's exhausted, etc. Also unlike a list, it's *lazy*—the values don't exist until you ask for them.) So:

```
values = return_some_values(False, True, True)
for i in value:
    print(i)
```

… will print out `1`, then print out `2`.

See the tutorial section on [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and the following section on Generators for a longer introduction. And [Generator Tricks for System Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/) is also very helpful.